# How or can I use Tor for downloading torrents?

Tags: vpn, bittorrent

As torrents sites are bloacked at my college so I think I can use Tor to access them but I want to download some of them so is there a way to use Tor to download torrent? Or if Tor can give me trackers for that...I would like to ask one more thing rather than posting another question that is, is there any Tor software also not the browser but software which come for linux? Please help me as I am a newcomer.